# MySql Query get record from tree table

Tags: php, mysql

What query to get record where the result in the same table?

I have table like this:

```
id uid  name  status    parent
1  1t01 AAA   Teacher   root
2  2s01 CCC   Student   1t01
3  3t02 BBB   Teacher   root
4  4s02 DDD   Student   3t02
5  5s03 EEE   Student   1t01
```

where i have Name : DDD and i won display teacher name : BBB

what query for get the teacher name : BBB

Solved

Answer from Martin

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90346/2/0)

Comment: please give the structure of tearcher table? and also any primary key made in that table to maintain relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table on itself, like so:

```
SELECT p.name teacher
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN table_name p
  ON p.uid = t.parent
WHERE t.name = 'BBB';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM yourtable t1, yourtable t2 
WHERE t1.parent = t2.uid 
AND t1.name = 'DDD';
```

Replace `yourtable` with your actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table Name where name="BBB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining same table will do so :

```
SELECT t2 .name as teacherName
FROM t1
JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t1.parent = t2.uid
WHERE t1.name = 'BBB';
```